# Python Request module, getting SSLError even with verify=False

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests, urllib3

When I tried to get the web page with Python Requests module for the first time on Elementary OS, I faced with SSLError. There is simple solution:

Python 3, trying:

```
import requests
page = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
```

Getting SSLError:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /home/led/PycharmProjects/urllib_p/urllib_p.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 549, in urlopen
    conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 251, in _get_conn
    return conn or self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 764, in _new_conn
    raise SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL "
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/led/PycharmProjects/urllib_p/urllib_p.py", line 5, in <module>
    page = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
```

verify=False make no sense (same Error)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Python_directory/Modules (Python-3.6.4/Modules in my case).
2. Open Setup file with text editor and search for SSL. You will find this:

   ```
   # Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
   # socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
   #SSL=/usr/local/ssl
   #_ssl _ssl.c \
   #   -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
   #   -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
   ```
3. Uncomment last four lines.
4. In terminal: go to Python_directory, then:

   ```
   sudo ./configure
   sudo make
   sudo make install
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with those commands:

```
sudo cp -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib/
sudo cp -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -sfn /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -sfn /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -sfn /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib/
```